# "deemed + noun": Is "deemed" an attributive modifier?

Tags: word-usage, modifiers, attributives

A definition on Merriam Webster says:

> lacking restraint
>   especially : marked by indulgence in things (such as drink or promiscuous sex)
>   **deemed vices** ([source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dissolute))

This definition is a bit confusing, because I am not sure if it means:

> marked by indulgence in things *and* deemed vices

Is that line saying that "deemed vices" is among the things one indulges in? If this is the case, is "deemed vices" a noun phrase here and "deemed" an attributive modifier?

Having checked several dictionary pages on "deem", I haven't found an example of "deemed" + noun. Is "deemed" used as an attributive modifier before a noun? If so what does it mean? "reputed"?

Comment: Why the downvote? Can the user who cast the downvote explain please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the actual definition [as it's formatted](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dissolute):

> **Definition of dissolute**
>
> : lacking restraint
>   *especially* : marked by indulgence in things (such as drink or promiscuous sex) deemed vices (see VICE entry 1 sense 1)
>   // leading a *dissolute* lifestyle
>   // the *dissolute* and degrading aspects of human nature
>   — Wallace Fowlie

This is a single sentence:

> marked by indulgence in things (such as drink or promiscuous sex) deemed vices (see VICE entry 1 sense 1)

If you remove the parenthetical information, you end up with this:

> marked by indulgence in things deemed vices

There is no *and*, implied or otherwise.

The meaning of the sentence can be made clearer with a slight rephrasing:

> marked by **an** indulgence in things **that are** deemed **to be** vices

Comment: And this is a passive voice construction, so even more explicitly, it's "things that people have deemed to be vices".

Comment: Thank you! I think it's probably a browser alignment issue that causes the line to break up on my computer. _deemed vices_ shows in a separate line on my end, and that's where I was stuck.